# Getting all values of permuation importnace

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection

I calculated the permutation Importance using `eli5`. But I only get a subset of the values.

```
import eli5
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X.columns.tolist())
```

[image]

At the end of the original  plot `..10 more` is shown. How can I get all the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `show_weights` method has a `top` argument, which when set to `None` there is no limit in the shown features (see the [documentation](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/eli5.html#eli5.show_weights)), so that should fix your problem:

```
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X.columns.tolist(), top=None)
```

Comment: Any tip for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60489934/5025009) issue?