# `eli5.show_weights` displayed standard deviation does not agree with the values in `feature_importances_std_`

Tags: python, scikit-learn, eli5

The `PermutationImportance` object has some nice attributes such as `feature_importances_` and `feature_importances_std_`.

To visualize in an HTML style this attributes I used `eli5.show_weights` function. However, I noticed that the displayed standard deviation does not agree with the values in `feature_importances_std_`.

***More specifically, I can see that the displayed HTML values are equal to `feature_importances_std_ * 2`. Why is that ?***

Code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
from sklearn.svm import SVC, SVR

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

clf = SVC()
perms = PermutationImportance(clf, n_iter=1000, cv=10, random_state=0).fit(X, y)

print(perms.feature_importances_)
# this is the actual SD
print(perms.feature_importances_std_)
# These are the displayed values
print(perms.feature_importances_std_* 2)

[0.39527333 0.17178   ] # the actual mean
[0.13927548 0.11061278] # the actual SD
[0.27855095 0.22122556] # the displayed values by `show_weights()`

eli5.show_weights(perms)
```

We can see that the diplayed standard deviation is doupled i.e. `2 * perms.feature_importances_std_`.

Is this a bug maybe?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with explain_weights in place of show_weights? Are the results same?

Comment: I have tried, yes. Nothing changes. See here: https://pasteboard.co/IXF26AD.png

Comment: For feature importances, you can also use [rfpimp](https://pypi.org/project/rfpimp/).

Comment: funny thing, they also use `eli5`. See last code cell here: https://github.com/parrt/random-forest-importances/blob/master/notebooks/pimp.ipynb

Comment: Is that only for random forest models? **Funny thing**, they also use `eli5`. See last code cell [here](https://github.com/parrt/random-forest-importances/blob/master/notebooks/pimp.ipynb)

Comment: I tried your code and replaced SVC() with RandomForestClassifier(), and the `x2` is still there. Therefore it's probably in the display and not in the computation.

Comment: Yes I have also opened a github issue request where I really explain line by line that it’s not a model related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the `*2` :
It's in the template generating the feature importances html table in the following page

https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/blob/63e99182dc682bbf225355c80a24807396a747b6/eli5/templates/feature_importances.html

```
        {% if not fw.std is none %}
            &plusmn; {{ "%0.4f"|format(2 * fw.std) }}
        {% endif %}
```

It's clearly put by hand

Comment: Great. That’s what I needed to know. Still unclear (probably it’s a bug) why they do that. My GitHub issue is still open. Your answer is on spot so I accept it

Comment: Yeah that's odd. I actually don't see the logic, and there is nothing written anywhere about it. I'll have a look at your github issue.